# Understand the order of commands in bash when functions are involved

Tags: bash

I have an example where I define a function named `f` which prints `blah` and then stores command itself and all its arguments into variable `$@`:

```
# f () { echo blah; "$@"; }
# df -h | f
blah
# df -h | f cat
blah
Filesystem                                              Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
rootfs                                                   37G   36G     0 100% /
udev                                                     10M     0   10M   0% /dev
tmpfs                                                   304M  308K  303M   1% /run
/dev/disk/by-uuid/466fbdef-029c-4625-8bb2-cde3acd77e55   37G   36G     0 100% /
tmpfs                                                   5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                                                   2.1G     0  2.1G   0% /run/shm
/dev/sda2                                                74G  7.0G   63G  11% /home
/dev/sr1                                                5.6M  5.6M     0 100% /media
#
```

How does this `f cat` part on the right of the pipe work? How does the stdout of `df -h` end up in the `$@` variable? Why does `cat` print the content of the `$@` variable?

Comment: "Why does cat print the content of the $@ variable?" `cat` *is* `$@`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In:

```
df -h | f
```

You redirected `df -h` output to `f` standard in, then called `f` without any arguments, `$@` is empty.

In other hand:

```
df -h | f cat
```

You redirected `df -h` output to `f` standard in, then called `f` with one argument `cat`. `"$@"` inside `f` expanded to `cat`. `cat` concatenated standard in, which is `df -h` output, to standard out.

Comment: I see, thanks! So basically in case of `df -h | f cat` after executing `df -h` part a new subshell is made and `f` function/command is executed which has `cat` as its only argument? In addition, how did the output of `df -h` "survive" up to `cat` command when before the `cat` there was `echo blah`? I mean `echo a | echo b; cat` obviously does not print `a`.

Comment: @Martin: In `echo a | echo b; cat`, `cat` is not part of pipeline. You need group command to do that. Try `echo a | {echo b; cat;}`